# Why does the field become half and overlap when I add the international code script?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I wanted to add the international number code dropdown to my code so that the user can select that and not enter it manually each time. It's not too important so I didn't bother learning how to validate it. [I recorded the issue and how it is fixed in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GXTV.jpg) by removing the `padding` part in the `section.contact-us #contact input` in the user CSS only for this `input` field, but it ruins other fields. I need the `padding` for other input fields besides this one. Also, the cursor begins to enter text below the dropdown is another issue that is fixed when removing the `padding`.(demonstrated in video) I attempted to add minimal code here to explain my issue, but the video should be more helpful.

Tldr: How can I make only one `input` tag to ignore the parent CSS definition for `input`? (The video above would make sense)

Edit: How can I concatenate the country code and the phone number during submission through JS? I use a google form's backend to submit the form. Not the best technique but serves my purpose. I'm not a core developer, so would appreciate help.

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.css" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
fieldset {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
section.contact-us #contact input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f4f7fb;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
</style>

<section class="contact">
<form id="contact-us">
 <div class="col-lg-6" style="position:relative;">
  <p class="required-form">*</p>
   <fieldset>
     <input type="tel" name="blah" id="whatsappno" placeholder="Whatsapp number" required/>
   </fieldset>
 </div>

</form>
<script>
   const phoneInputField = document.querySelector("#whatsappno");
   const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {
   utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
    });
</script>
<script>
 <script>
              function postToGoogle() {
                
                var field3 = $("#whatsappno").val();
                

         



                $.ajax({
                  url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/…….?”,
                  data: {“…….”: field3 },
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "xml",
                  success: function (d) {
                  },
                  error: function (x, y, z) {

                    $('#success-msg').show();
                    $('#contact').hide();

                  }
                });
                return false;
              }
</script>

</section>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use such specific CSS selectors. Make a rule for `<input>` in general, and then add classes to specific `<input>` elements to use specific layout properties.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. Did not occur to me somehow.